# Try again when error occurs

Tags: java, loops, error-handling

I want to try 3 times when error happened.
What I have done so far....

```
public class TryTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TryTest test = new TryTest();
        test.tryThis();
    }

    public void tryThis() {
        int a = 10;
        int x = 0;
        int count = 1;
        try {
            System.out.println("Test " + count);
            a = a / x;
            System.out.println("Success !");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (count <= 3) {
                // I want to try again with new x value
                count++;
                x++;
            }
            System.out.println("ERROR:\t" + e);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Finish");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you could use a class variable `count` and recall the function `tryThis()` inside your catch clause. That'd be one way to do it.

Comment: What exactly you will be trying three times? From code you have provided it is pretty useless to try three times, it will always fail first time and succeed the second. What's the point here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a loop, which loops using you have a done values [0, 3)

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Test " + count);
        int a = 10 / i;
        System.out.println("Success !");
        break;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR:\t" + e);
    }
 }
 System.out.println("Finish");
```

Comment: +1 but since op wants to reiterate just on failures, I'd add a break in there

Comment: I want to try again only when there is error, not 3 times always.

Comment: Ok, added a `break;` on success.

Comment: Also changed the counter so it will repeat up to 3 times, not up to a count of 3 (which is 4 times)

Comment: Seems perfect to me now. For the sake of knowledge: I suggest OP to have a look at what break and continue instructions do in java loops. (I suspect that this is what OP was implicitly asking)